# Radius of Convergence of $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-z^{2}\sqrt{n}}$

Tags: complex-analysis, power-series

Find all $z \in \mathbb{C}$ such that the series

$$ F(z)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} e^{-z^{2}\sqrt{n}}$$

converges.

I tried the ratio test and root test, but both were inconclusive. I considered the Cauchy-Hadamard formula, but could not see how to apply it to this problem.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Comment: Since it's not a power series, the Cauchy-Hadamard formula doesn't apply. Start by finding out for which $z$ you have $e^{-z^2\sqrt{n}} \to 0$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $z=x+iy$ then $z^2=(x^2-y^2)+i(2xy)$ and 
$$e^{-z^{2}\sqrt{n}}=e^{(y^2-x^2)\sqrt{n}}\cdot e^{-2xyi\sqrt{n}}.$$
Note that $|e^{-z^{2}\sqrt{n}}|=e^{(y^2-x^2)\sqrt{n}}\to 0$ iff $|x|>|y|$ which implies that the series does not converge when $|x|\leq |y|$.

Moreover if $|x|>|y|$ then
$$n^2|e^{-z^{2}\sqrt{n}}|=n^2e^{(y^2-x^2)\sqrt{n}}=e^{(y^2-x^2)\sqrt{n}+2\ln n}\to 0$$
because $(y^2-x^2)\sqrt{n}+2\ln n\to -\infty$ as $n\to+\infty$.
Hence eventually $|e^{-z^{2}\sqrt{n}}|\leq \frac{1}{n^2}$. Since the series $\sum\frac{1}{n^2}$ is convergent, we conclude that that series converges iff $|x|>|y|$.

Answer (score -1):

I will look at the convergence of $\sum\limits_{n=0}^{\infty}{e^{r\sqrt{n}}}$ for $r$ real. Can you see how it's related to your problem?

For $r\ge 0$, we have $e^{r\sqrt{n}}\ge 1$ for all $n$, and hence the series diverges.

For $r<0$, note that for large enough $n$ we have $r\sqrt{n} < -2\log n$, so for large enough $n$ we have $e^{r\sqrt{n}}< n^{-2}$. Thus, by the comparison test the series converges.

Comment: "Can you see how it's related to your problem?" Related, yes, but sufficient to solve it, certainly not.

Comment: Sorry, I should have made that clear: it is *not* sufficient, and that wasn't the intent. I was hoping the OP can take some ideas from this solution and apply it to the original problem.

Comment: FYI, I myself fail to see how I should "take some ideas from this solution and apply it to the original problem." The original problem is *different*.

Comment: Fine. For any $z\in\mathbb{C}$, there exists a real number $r$ such that $|e^{-z^2\sqrt{n}}| = e^{r\sqrt{n}}$ for all $n\in\mathbb{N}$. Does that help?